# Joining poorly designed SQL tables?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've tried searching for information on joining tables without foriegn keys but it seems the answer is always to create the foreign key. I cannot modify the tables in question to do this and I must report on data that is already in production. The following is a portion of the data in the tables involved in order to exemplify the issue.

```
Table A
Journal    Account    Debit    Credit    Sequence
--------------------------------------------------
87041      150-00     100.00   0.00      16384
87041      150-10     0.00     100.00    32768
87041      150-00     50.0     0.0       49152
87041      210-90     0.0      50.0      65536
```

Then the second table, tracking additional bits of information, is largely the same but missing the Sequence number that would tie the line items together properly. It has its own Sequence Number that is unrelated.

```
Table B
Journal    Account    Label    Artist    Sequence
--------------------------------------------------
87041      150-00     Label02  Artist12  1
87041      150-10     Label09  Artist03  2
87041      150-00     Label04  Artist01  3
87041      210-90     Label01  Artist05  4
```

At present the best I can come up with is to join on Journal and Account but that duplicates records. I have gotten close by playing around with grouping and max() on sequence number but the result has been that that not all duplicates are removed for journal entries with a very large number of rows and the first match from the second table is always displayed for lines that have the same account.

```
Closest - but bad - result
Journal    Account    Debit    Credit    Sequence    Label    Artist
----------------------------------------------------------------------
87041      150-00     100.00   0.00      16384       Label02  Artist12
87041      150-10     0.00     100.00    32768       Label09  Artist03
87041      150-00     50.0     0.0       49152       Label02  Artist12  <-- wrong 
87041      210-90     0.0      50.0      65536       Label01  Artist05
```

How can I join the tables such that duplicates are excluded but also so that the correct Label and Artist are displayed? It sort of feels like I have to produce a query which knows that one of the records from Table B has already been used when the 49152 record from Table A comes looking for a match.

EDIT:

@Justin Crabtree A.Sequence will be the order in which the line items were entered. So a user could have entered the last line in the example first, then the first line, then the third, and finally the second.

@Edper Microsoft SQL Server...hmm, I cannot remote into the client's machine this morning...otherwise I would provide the version.

@Abe Miessler yes, you are correct.

As soon as I can get back into the server I will try your suggestion @pkuderov

Comment: That your asking for sounds possible... but is difficult to exactly pin down.  Please paste the SQL that you used to get the result.  When there are multiple records in Table B - which record should be used?

Comment: I think I understand now, one of the problem's you'll face is that it wont be 100% reliable to trust the natural order in the tables of the elements - this will maych up in most cases to the order in the other table but isn't consistent without fail.  Is it possible to trust the Sequence in Table A to atleast be in the right order?

Comment: @CodenameCain What RDBMS are you using sqlserver or mysql or something else?

Comment: Could you post what your desired output would be?  Should the row marked `wrong` have `Label04  Artist01` instead?

Comment: Unless you know something you haven't told us, it's not possible. Now you know why we advocate for foreign keys, and why we don't recommend building your own accounting software. The best thing for *you* to do is to turn this problem over to the person who designed the tables.

Comment: *"I've tried searching for information on joining tables without foriegn keys but it seems the answer is always to create the foreign key."* Both the relational model and SQL base joins on common values. You don't have to use foreign key *constraints* to join on common values. Your problem *here* is that these two tables don't have *enough* common values to perform joins correctly. (And a foreign key between these two tables would have prevented that problem.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi, that's just an idea:

```
select
    a.Journal, a.Account, a.Debit, a.Credit, a.Sequence, b.Label, b.Artist
from (
    select
        *, 
        row_number() over(partition by Journal, Account order by Sequence) as idInGroup
    from a
) as a
join (
    select
        *, 
        row_number() over(partition by Journal, Account order by Sequence) as idInGroup
    from b
) as b on
    a.Journal = b.Journal
    and a.Account = b.Account
    and a.idInGroup = b.idInGroup
```

Here I assume that orders appeared in Sequence order (in both tables) and that's the base hint for join tables.

Comment: I've successfully implemented this example. @JKan I was also wondering about the order. Each transaction I've examined in detail shows a good matching order thus far.

Answer (score 4):

Try [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b05f7/3)

```
;WITH a AS
(
    SELECT Journal,
           Account,
           Debit,
           Credit,
           Sequence,
           Id = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Journal ORDER BY Sequence)
    FROM dbo.tablea
)
, b AS
(
    SELECT Journal,
           Account,
           Label,
           Artist,
           Id = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Journal ORDER BY Sequence)
    FROM dbo.tableb
)

SELECT a.Journal,
       a.Account,
       a.Debit,
       a.Credit,
       a.Sequence,
       b.Label,
       b.Artist
FROM a
JOIN b ON b.Journal = a.Journal
      AND b.Account = a.Account
      AND b.Id = a.Id
```

Comment: won't work if there're rows with different B.Journal and B.Sequence is shared for all B.Journal. So you no need to do partition on A at all or do it on B too

Comment: @pkuderov hence "given the data provided". I +1'd your answer which tbh is probably more correct

Comment: @TI and last little grammar fix needed - you forgot to change `tableb` to `b` in join clause :)

Comment: @TI ah, sry, just checked if really a.Account = b.Account isn't needed in join clause. And it's needed. Just check your join on given data - Journal is the same and id's are: [1, 1, 2, 1] for A and [1, 1, 2, 1]. All rows with id = 1 will join with each other (but it's wrong if we need to keep Accounts equality).

Answer (score 0):

If you ordered the 2 table rows by their own sequence numbers, will the rows align in the same order?

If so, this is a possible solution for SQL server:
You can create 2 CTEs, one for each table, with ROW_NUMBER column, and that way, both tables will have a matching row number column that you can use to join. Let me know if you need an example.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your requirements correctly and you want all rows from Table A, but only the first matching row from Table B, your best bet would be to do an OUTER APPLY with a TOP(1). That would look something like this:

```
select *
from TableA
OUTER APPLY
 (select TOP(1) Journal, Account, Label, Artist, Sequence
  FROM TableB
  WHERE Journal = TableA.Journal AND Account = TableA.Account
  ORDER BY Sequence) as B
```

(Definitely pseudo-code, but that should be somewhat close.)

If it comes down to it, you could use ROW_NUMBER(), partition that by Journal and Account and then match on those Row_Number values for each result set.  You'd generate one sub-query/CTE for TableA and another CTE for TableB - each with a RowNumber value that would be essentially a new sequence integer. The first row in TableA would match the first row in TableB, Second row in TableA would match the second in TableB, etc. Of course, you'd run into some issues if there are more rows for Journal/Account in "A" than there are in "B".

A better question might be - "How does your code determine all matches between TableA and TableB if they can't use any data columns to tie them together?"